# Using css to place an image at the top of the page and the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to find a solution to this without much success. I am basically trying to place an image using a background property at the top and bottom of the page. Now I know I can make the positioning relative and it would place the image at the bottom move according to how much content is on the page.

I can also make the header/footer an absolute position and effectively just have the user scroll between them. But I want to make it where if there is not a whole lot of content, I want to place the image at the bottom of the page, and if there happens to be a lot of content (i.e. that the user has to scroll through), the image gets placed at the bottom.

This is just a little thing I am trying to figure out for myself so any ideas/suggestion or tutorials on this would be greatly appreciated. I would rather not use tables to layout my page and wondering how to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you apply `padding-bottom` to your `<body>` and then use `background-image` to apply your image to it? If not, see my answer to this question for how to make a footer DIV stick to the bottom of the page: [Sticky footer, or rather: content doesn't stretch down to footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385313/sticky-footer-or-rather-content-doesnt-stretch-down-to-footer/9385765#9385765)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this:

| IMG |

| CONTENT |

| FOOTER |

then why do you need to use absolute positioning? If you have 3 divs, one on top of the other, with a certain width and the property `clear:both`, then the arrangement would be automatic. Then, in case you have a page with very little content, you can put a `min-height` to the content div.

Answer (score 0):

For the first image that is the header, set the position to 'fixed' and top to 0px:

```
.first-image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

For the second image that is the footer, set the position to 'fixed' and bottom to 0px;

```
.second-image {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do this, but I would rather have it such that the images are not fixed on the page. I don't want them to appear as the user starts scrolling content. Only when there is little content do I want them both to appear on the window at the same time, else the footer image should just *adjust* itself to the bottom of the content.

Comment: I guess it's a little unclear as to exactly what you're trying to achieve based on the original question. May be you can draw a wireframe?