# Sticky footer chrome does not work with dynamic contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, compass-sass

I have recently noticed, that in some versions of Google Chrome the classic css-only sticky footer solution used by compass do not work, when contents is generated by script. The footer just cover the contents instead of moving down. The layout will change to correct one when you resize your window. The css/html in compass is based on solution provided on http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
 height: 4em;
}
```

With following html:

Any ideas, how to fix this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
       <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue. It seems to be a chrome bug. 
Since on `window.resize` chrome will repaint the buggy footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add `clear:both`

```
.footer, .push  
  {
 clear:both; 
 height: 4em;
  }
```

or try this link

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: try this one,may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385313/sticky-footer-or-rather-content-doesnt-stretch-down-to-footer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: No, the problem is with dynamically generated contents. Everything works with statically generated contents, or in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. A dynamic table was getting overlapped, but none of my other pages. This solution worked for me.

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;      /*!! margin: 0 auto -4em; !!*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
p {
    margin-top:0;
}
.push{
    height:4em;
}
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.footer{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    height: 4em;
    margin-top:-4em; /*!!!*/
}
```

Comment: I know, there are lot of css solutions based on 100% trick. The problem is, that none of them works in case of dynamically generated contents in chrome.